# Mongoose Mixed Schema not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to set mixed Schema in ExpressJs I tried to use *mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed* didn´t worked and tried explicit as shown bellow but unfortunately it fails with same error:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" app.js
>
> c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:247
>   **app.getDetail = app.get;**
>                        ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at Function.Model.register (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:247:22)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\routes\api.js:10:8)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\app.js:18:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>
> Process finished with exit code 8

```
/**
 * Created by User on 3/8/2015.
 */
var  restful = require("node-restful");

var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var storeSchema = new  mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   products: [new mongoose.Schema({
      name : String,
      description : String
   })]

});
module.exports = restful.model("store", storeSchema);


/**
 * Created by User on 3/8/2015.
 */
var express = require("express");

var router = express().Router;

var stores = require ("../models/store");
stores.methods(["get","post","put","delete"]);
stores.register(router,"stores");

module.exports = router;
```

New Error:

> c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:228
>           app[key](prefix + '/:id([0-9a-fA-F]{0,24}$)?', handlerlist);
>                   ^ TypeError: Object function createApplication() {   var app = function(req, res, next) {
>       app.handle(req, res, next);   };
>
> mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);   mixin(app, proto,
>   false);
>
> app.request = { **proto**: req, app: app };   app.response = {
>   **proto**: res, app: app };   app.init();   return app; } has no method 'get'
>       at Function.Model.registerRoutes (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:228:17)
>       at Function.Model.register (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\node_modules\node-restful\lib\model.js:248:8)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\routes\api.js:10:8)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodekid\app.js:18:17)

Comment: The error originates in `api.js` line 10, can you post that part of your code?

Comment: /**
 * Created by User on 3/8/2015.
 */
var express = require("express");

var router = express().Router;

var stores = require ("../models/store");
stores.methods(["get","post","put","delete"]);
stores.register(router,"stores");

module.exports = router;

Comment: @victorkohl check above

Answer (score 0):

The error was in api.js in setting routing:

```
var router = express().Router;
```

Just Change it with:

```
var router = express.Router();
```